# Is there a way to call a SignalR Hub from classes that aren't able to inject the HubContext via DI?

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture, signalr

The SignalR [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0) has a part where it explains how to use .NET's DI to inject the IHubContext into a controller/middleware, but is there any way to get a reference to/instance of a Hub from just any plain class? Does it have to specifically be a service or whatever else the DI requires in order to make this work?

To give a very contrived *(and possibly wrong)* example: Say we have a `TestHub` and a static `List<Whatever>`. Whenever a client connects to `TestHub`, we create a new `Whatever` and add it to the static list. Each `Whatever` does one thing: asynchronously waits a random amount of time, and then somehow calls `TestHub` to send a message to all clients.

Now, this might completely be an architectural issue, seeing as the static List can just as well be a Singleton service that *can* use DI, but the idea is that the List doesn't govern when the messages are sent, instead the `Whatever` objects do that, with the random wait abstracting some nondeterministic logic.

If this scenario makes any sense, how can the `Whatever` call the `TestHub`?

If it doesn't, please let me know what I'm getting wrong. I'm very new to this, so I'm not really sure if the use case makes much sense in general.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, no statics allowed. Put the class in DI and inject the IHubContext is the way to go! You can also consider using a [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/background-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

PS: Of course, you can create your own static but that's not a route I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks. A follow-up question, then, is how to get access to a DI-registered Singleton (`builder.Services.AddSingleton`) from a non-DI class. Doing that would probably work for my use case, since the List from the example would in reality just need to be a globally(-ish) accessible singleton.

Comment: You can't, but you can do something less recommended and resolve the service at startup, and store it in your static class.